# Moodle download a created PDF

Tags: php, tcpdf, moodle

I create a PDF in Moodle using the following code

```
$pdf = new pdf; 
$pdf->AddPage(); 
$pdf->Write(1, "Test"); 
$pdf->Output();
```

How would I make this download in the browser instead of opening in browser?

Comment: Moodle seems to be using fpdf for PDF generation. Have a look in the fpdf documentation, that will most probably help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Force the browser to download the output
$pdf->Output('filename.pdf','D');
```

Comment: That appears to be documentation for fpdf, not TCPDF (they may work similarly, but Moodle uses TCPDF).

Comment: @davosmith : but tag he used is `fpdf` either fpdf or tcpdf syntax which I showed should work

Comment: tcpdf is a fork of fpdf. It happens that the Output function is unchanged between the two, so your answer does work, but the link to the documentation is potentially misleading as other functions in the fpdf documentation may not match those that are being used within Moodle.

Comment: The fpdf tag was incorrectly added by @flomei, not by the original poster

Comment: @davosmith : thank you so much, in my answer I will remove doc part

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the syntax looked like pure fpdf code to me, so I added that tag.

Answer (score 1):

Moodle wraps the TCPDF library for PDF generation (the wrapper mostly just handles the locations for temporary files and accessing embedded images which are in the Moodle Files API).

You can find documentation about the TCPDF Output() function online at http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a3d6dcb62298ec9d42e9125ee2f5b23a1

The important param is the second one, calling $pdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'D') will cause it to download.